# CSS: floating, absolute position and overflow

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="copy">blabla</div>
    <div class="outside"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; }
.image { float: left; }
.outside { position: absolute; top: 0; left: -20px; }
```

I want `.outside` to extend outside the `.wrapper`, however there are two problems: as is, `.wrapper` does not extend down to accommodate for the floated `.image`; setting `.wrapper` to `overflow: auto` fixes the height issue, but hides the absolutely positioned `.outside`. How can I get both the height to stretch automatically and not have the absolutely positioned element be cut off?

**EDIT:** my wrapper is set to relative, sorry - forgot to add that. For further clarification, here are some crappy diagrams:

[image]
[image]
[image]

**EDIT 2:** I got it to work by adding a wrapper around the image and copy and setting it to `overflow: auto`. I wanted to avoid unnecessary markup, but oh well... Thanks everyone!

Comment: Where are the crappy diagrams? I only see 3 cool diagrams `:)`

Comment: OK, above are 3 awesome diagrams. :)

Comment: You could've also done it by setting something like a `clearfix` after the `image` class.

Comment: For some reason that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by adding an additional wrapper with `overflow: auto` around `.image` and `.copy`.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to clear your float.

Add another empty div like:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="copy">blabla</div>
    <div class="outside"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clearfix { clear: both; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Float the wrapper (add float: left to the css for .wrapper), or put `<BR style="clear: both;">` after the floated image.

Put the absolute div outside the wrapper, rather than inside it.

But why are you doing position absolute? I bet you don't need to do that, and if you gave more info on what you are trying to do there might be an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Position absolute will position it absolutely to the body unless its parent has a position other than static. If you want it positioned absolutely to the parent (`.wrapper`), you need to give `.wrapper` a position such as `position:relative;`

Then, add a div to clear your floats:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="copy">blabla</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="outside"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper { 
    background-color:red;
    width: 200px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    position:relative;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
.image { 
    float: left; 
}
.outside { 
    background-color:yellow;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: -20px; 
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/6Fmy2/